# wordpress static/post pages

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to make a wordpress page have posts and static content on it? Like have the latest posts but also have some content from the page on it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page
and here : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/387710

But seriously, I just google'd for "wordpress static content posts".

Comment: thanks man...your right. Sometimes I just instinctively head over to stackoverflow whenever I have a problem. 

Anyway, that second link fixed my problem. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible. You need to create a custom page template, however, so that you can edit the page content and also pull in the posts. (You can make them posts in just one category, if you want, and use some other tricks to hide those posts from the main blog page.)

See http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/02/power-tips-for-wordpress-template-developers/ for details.

Comment: I think I'll just make the content a post with its own unique category.